# MASM32 modular division

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

So I have a procedure here that should print an array initialized with "~". Since I want a 12x12 game board I use modular division on 144 by 12 and print a new line when the remainder is 0. I definitely have a problem somewhere though, my first hint is that it just crashes the second it goes to print the board.

```
displayBoard PROC
lea esi, dArray
mov eax, 144

.while eax > 0
    xor edx, edx
    mov ecx, 12
    div ecx
    .if edx == 0
        print 0DH, 0AH
    .endif
    print esi
    sub eax, 1
.endw

mov eax, input()
```

displayBoard ENDP

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `div` instruction sets both `edx` and `eax` - it does this:

```
eax := edx:eax DIV ecx
edx := edx:eax MOD ecx
```

So it overwrites the `eax` register and breaks your loop.

---

Additionally, `eax` is a temporary register and the call to `print` will overwrite it as well. See the ABI document or calling convention for your target platform to see which registers are and which are not preserved across function calls.

---

Finally, I don't know what `print` does, but using it both with immediate CR/LF values `0DH, 0AH` and `esi`, a pointer to some array, seems fishy.

Comment: Alright tyvm for the help I got it working based off of your comments. The last question I have is that using print esi will print the entire 144 elements in the array. For each loop I will want to print the next element which I am guessing means I have to print esi+1 since it is a BYTE array?

Comment: You need specify "a byte at address `esi`", which is written in MASM syntax as `print byte ptr [esi]`.